# Why does Dielectric Barrier Discharge (DBD) power scale with the driving frequency?

Tags: plasma-physics

While reading [this review on dielectric barrier discharges (DBDs)](http://www3.nd.edu/~sst/teaching/AME60637/reading/2003_PCPP_Kogelschatz_dbd_review.pdf), I came across an apparently widely-applicable formula for calculating the power of a  DBD.

The formula states that the DBD power is proportional to the frequency of the driving signal. According to the review paper:

> *The reason is that we generate the same number of identical microdischarges per period.*

Why would this be so? Increasing the driving frequency decreases the duration of each period. Why would the number of microdischarges per period remain unchanged?

Answer (score 0):

This explanation:

> *The reason is that we generate the same number of identical microdischarges per period.*

is valid for a particular range of frequencies (I would say in kHz range). Within this range, the period of the waveform in in microseconds, while the lifetime of each one of the microdischarges is in nanoseconds. So increasing or decreasing the period by factor of 2 or even 10 won't affect the microdischarges.

If you use a GHz frequency, you will end up with a different type of discharge with a different behaviour than that referred to in the review you cited.

Another way to look at it is from circuit perspective, a DBD is similar to RC circuit where the plasma is the resistor and the dielectric is the capacitor. When you increase the frequency, the impedance of the capacitor decreases, allowing more power to be consumed in the resistor, giving higher plasma power for higher frequency.

Hope this helps,